# A timer in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, timer, foreach, sendkeys

I made a code that read each line in a richtextbox with a foreach.

```
foreach (string str in textBox3.Lines)
{                
    SendKeys.Send(str + " \n");
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```

But the problem is that it crashes because of the many lines. So what I thought is to make a timer after the the Enter sendkey. I tried it with Thread.Sleep and all kind of things that I've searched on the internet, but with no result.

Comment: There is probably a better way to send that information to another application than simulating keyboard input.  That's probably your best bet, rather than adding a delay with that much data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SendWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Send`, it will not continue until the message has been processed by the receiver.

However, there are likely better ways to do what you want to do other than `SendKeys`, if you add more details of what you are trying to accomplish I can try and update this answer with other potentially better options.

Comment: I got another problem now. I made my textBox into a richTextBox. I've got a bunch of line in there, and want them to add them all 1 by 1 into another document. I have like 800 different lines in the richTextBox. The problem what I've got now is when I run it, when it's on line 15 of the richTextBox, that it goes back to line 1. I tried to put a timer after the SendKeys, System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1200). But it is still not working.